# PHP Accessing Array Value

Tags: php, arrays

i am trying to access the value of an array that i have created, but it seems to fail.

I am looping through an array that sends VIA http, and adding the `docno` and `entryno` to new array called `$ArrID`, it can be added to the new array, however when i try to access the `ArrID` it seem to get nothing from the `array` itself while i am confident that `ArrID` contain the items

CODE

```
$ArrID = [];
foreach ($form_data_body as $key => $value) {
  $docno = $value -> doc_no;
  $entryno = $value -> entryno;
  if($mysqli->query($sql) == 1){
    $itemArr = array('docno' => $docno, 'entryno' => $entryno);
    $ArrID[] = $itemArr;
  }
}

if(count($ArrID)>0){
    foreach ($ArrID as $key => $values) {
      echo $values -> docno;
    }
}
```

Comment: Is that `$value -> doc_no` really? or `$value['doc_no']`

Comment: `$value['doc_no']` echo the value, but why it is not using the sign `->` to access the value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mixing with `object` and `array`

see http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php
http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.object.php

```
$ArrID = [];
foreach ($form_data_body as $key => $value) {
  $docno = $value['doc_no'];
  $entryno = $value['entryno'];
  if($mysqli->query($sql) == 1){
    $itemArr = array('docno' => $docno, 'entryno' => $entryno);
    $ArrID[] = $itemArr;
  }
}

if(count($ArrID)>0){
    foreach ($ArrID as $key => $values) {
      echo $values['docno'];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How are you sure that your array has the data? Make sure by echoing the size of the array and see if its greater then zero.

Try the code below and check if it works or not. There was a redundant assign and reassign code, actually you were assigning array to a variable, and variable to an array again.

```
$ArrID = [];
foreach ($form_data_body as $key => $value) {
  $docno = $value -> doc_no;
  $entryno = $value -> entryno;
  if($mysqli->query($sql) == 1) {
    $ArrID[] = array('docno' => $docno, 'entryno' => $entryno); 
  }
}
if(count($ArrID)>0) {
  foreach ($ArrID as $key => $values) {
    echo $values -> docno;
  }
}
```

Comment: i put the condition `if(count($ArrID)>0){` and echoing some dummy data if hit the condition and it does hit the condition

Comment: so does it output anything? the docno as u feed it or something else?

Comment: something else, not the `docno`, i put `echo "got it";` right after the `if(count($ArrID)>0){` and before `foreach ($ArrID as $key => $values) {` and it does echoing the `got it` so i am assume the array is not empty.

Comment: make sure u r not echoing the memory address, its been 4 years i didnt touch php. but if array is not empty and it hits the condition either u receive the data in wrong format OR ur echoing th memory location instead.

Comment: as @ASR posted above, `$value['docno']` should be used io `$value -> docno` just wonder what the problem with those syntax